# Hide div content permanently

Tags: javascript, php

I want when the user click on submit button the content disappear (`random text 3`) until the user logs off. The JS works fine but, if I refresh the page, the content appears. Can anyone help me achieve this or can anyone convert my code to PHP so that I can use a session variable to achieve this?

```
 <style type="text/css">
    div.something{
       /*random code;/*
    }
 </style>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function hideSomething(){
       document.getElementsByClassName("something")[2].style.display = "none";
    }
 </script>

 <div class="something">random text 1</div>
 <div class="something">random text 2</div>
 <div class="something">random text 3</div><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Disappear" onclick="hideSomething()" />
```

Comment: you will have to record that the user hid the div, then use js\php to re-hide for that user.

Comment: Any sample code please?

Comment: well the professional way is to record it on cookie or store in database with user information like IP or you can use rough way to just forward it to another page where that div not appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first we create a form with a hidden text box, once user click on button **Close Attendance** the value of hidden textbox is submited and a session variable is created:

```
if(isset($_POST['hidden'])){
$_SESSION['closed'] = TRUE;
}
```

Then we check is session is set, if yes display attendance close, if not display content.

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['closed'])){
        echo "attendance closed.";
                } 
     else {
               echo "<form name='test' action='attendance.php' method='post'>
         <input type='hidden' name='hidden'/>
         <button> Close Attendance </button>
          </form>"; 
                }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

well the professional way is to record it on cookie or store in database with user information like IP or you can use rough way to just forward it to another page where that div not appear thou some dont allow cookies to store let me know which one you like and i will fill my answer with it sample

Comment: can u please give me a sample

Answer (score 0):

Use a cookie and store the status of the div there.
You can easily read and write a cookie using javascript.
A nice tutorial can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp.

For example, in the hideSomething() function do the following:

document.cookie="display_div=true";

Then, when the page is loaded, call a javascript function that shows or hide the div based on the value of the cookie:

if(cookie_value == "true")
 //Hide your div
else
 //Show your div.
end

Comment: hello i've tried what you told me, can u please tell me where is my error:
`<script type="text/javascript">
function hideSomething()
{
document.getElementsByClassName("something")[2].style.display = "none";
document.cookie="display_div=true";
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
if(cookie_value == "true") {
document.getElementsByClassName("something")[2].style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
HTML code
<body onload="myFunction()">
//same as upstairs
</body>`

Answer (score 0):

try the following code, it should give you a very clear glimpse on how to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>ZUUS: Ironman</title>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function hideSomething() 
        { 
            document.cookie="hide_div=true"; 
            myFunction();
        } 

        function myFunction() 
        { 
            var cookie_value = getCookie("hide_div");
            alert(cookie_value);
            if(cookie_value == "true") 
                document.getElementById("test_div").style.display = "none"; 
        } 

        function getCookie(cname)
        {
            var name = cname + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
          {
            var c = ca[i].trim();
            if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
          }
            return "";
        }
    </script>
    <body onload="myFunction();">
        <div id="test_div" style="background-color: blue;" onclick="hideSomething();">
            this is a test
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```